# Output redirect of nested script not working with cron

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have this shell script, that dynamically builds another script and calls it (i.e. a nested script).

Something like this, let's say it is called `the_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# do some stuff here, and create another script
./nested_script.sh

# do some other stuff, end
```

If I just call `./the_script.sh` it outputs everything to STDOUT, including the nested script's output.

But if it runs from a cronjob, like so:

```
0 8,12 * * 1-5 /home/myuser/the_script.sh >> /home/myuser/thescript.log
```

Then it does not output the nested script's result, which is very important for me. The result of both script is correct however it is run (from the prompt or cron), and it runs as expected.

Any clues on why this happens and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display error in log adding `2>&1`

```
0 8,12 * * 1-5 /home/myuser/the_script.sh >> /home/myuser/thescript.log 2>&1
```

Then it will display something like `: No such file or directory`, this is because current working directory is not the shell's directory. The cleanest is to use absolute path, otherwise `cd -- "$(dirname "${0:-.}")"`

Comment: That worked, thanks. And there was no error displayed anywhere. It just outputed everything I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The cron does not run from a specific user's home directory - so running ./nested_script.sh may not work.  You should specify the absolute path to this so the cron knows exactly where it is.

Comment: It does work. It runs as expected. It just doesn't output anything.

Comment: This is working for me, using two scripts both with a single echo in. Could you post minimal code where this is failing?

Comment: Try running nested_script.sh with source and so "source nested_script.sh"

Comment: `echo` is not really a good way to test it because it will always output. I'm just calling a `mongodump` inside that nested script, and it has its own ouput. BTW, `source` didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you two important hints:

1. note that in `nested_script.sh` or `the_script.sh` body, is there any command with `-i` or `--interactive` parameter? if so, the caller shell executes an interactive shell for you, specially with addition `-t` or `--tty` parameter. thus the caller shell (crontab) must catch returned STDOUT from such command which include --tty. but it can't handle and returned result of that command will fail. so you should remove `-i or -t` options if you could. or you need to change your scripts to avoid `-i or -t`. I tackled with such trouble before. I wrote a cron schedule like this:

   `* * * * * /path/to/my-backup-script.sh`

and here was my-backup-script.sh body

`#!/bin/sh
docker exec -it my_cont mysqldump --user=myuser --password=dbpass  my_db |gzip > /path/for/bk/my-backup.gz`

I finally found that `-it` parameter was the problem. because shell wanted to return results to cron, but it failed.

2. note that in cases you are using commands whose parameters are again a command. for example `sshpass -p mypass command [options]` . in such cases note carefully if your desired command first, is defined in crontab env (including **which command** returned result in `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin: ...` at the beginning of cron file). second, it does not return values which are needed to response to by user. for example **rm** command may prompt for confirm remove. if such command scripted in cron, it works without error but may not do the exact action you want.